# Do architecturally correct the texture/shader/material/VB/IB bind itself?

Tags: architecture, game-engine

I am writing the game engine and can't solve what way is correct.
I will show you one material class for example.

First way:

```
class Material {
  public:
    void Bind(); // bind all that can: uniforms, textures, vertex shader, fragment shader, etc
};

// somewhere in scene manager
...
  material.Bind();
  // below is binding all params and resources that material require from outside
  if (material.IsRequireWVP()) glUniform(...);
  if (material.IsRequireModelTexture()) glBindTexture(...);
...
```

Second way:

```
class Material {
      public:
        TexGLES2Ref GetTexture();
        VSGLES2Ref GetVertexShader();
        string GetUniformName();
        value getUniformValue();
        // etc 
    };

// somewhere in scene manager
...
  // bind all resources that material need here
  // material has no bind method 
  glUniform(material->get(....), material->get(...));

  if (material.IsRequireWVP()) glUniform(...);
  if (material.IsRequireModelTexture()) glBindTexture(...);
...
```

Because "Book can't read itself" I use the second way,
but this way is less comfortable than first, because if I need to bind material from many code places then I must write a lot of code as material has passes, uniforms, textures, etc. and that is "cycle in cycle in cycle". The first solution I imagine is write function like `BindMaterial(Material *material);` In this case "book doesn't read itself".

But I see a lot of code with first way and thinking that there must be some argument for using first case. Maybe coders just reject "Book can't read itself" and use way that is more comfortable for them?

**Which way is better and more correct?**

**What way do you use and why?**